# c# show heat image from temperature matrix

Tags: c#, graphics, temperature, heat

I'm building a program in C# that calculates the spread of heat in a surface. I performed all the physical mathematical calculation and got the results in matrixes. (DataTable, which i added a functionallity to convert to float[,]).
I want to present this heat expansion in a graphical way as heat image like so:
[image: Heat Expansion Image]

I'm not looking for the most efficient way, I'm just looking for the simplest quickest way.

Comment: You can manipulate a bitmap's pixels directly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20182830/996081

Comment: The simplest way usually is not the quickest way. How many data do you have?

Comment: I meant the quickest and simplest to code.. And I've got over 50,000 cells in the array..
anyway, I found a solution online using OpenCL OpenGL