# Why AccessViolationException occurs when accessing pixels in WriteableBitmap Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, writablebitmap

I have a video stream from a camera to an Image in a WPF. I am trying to access the  WritableBitMap Image pixel by pixel before displaying it. As a test I am trying to set the whole image to white or black. In both cases however, I get the AccessViolationException error.

I checked other posts and it seems that this error is very wide and not specific to my case. I can't seem to know why I am not getting this working.

So what is the best way to play with the pixels in my case? or why this is not working? Any help is appreciated

```
     private async void UpdateMasterCameraPreview(IdsFrame frame)
    {
        if (masterImage != null)
            frame.Image.CopyTo(masterImage);
        else
            masterImage = frame.Image.ToWriteableBitmap();

        //BitmapImage temp = ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmapImage(masterImage);
        WriteableBitmap temp = masterImage;

        // Here I get the exception, on every pixel access
        for (int y = 0; y < temp.PixelHeight; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < temp.PixelWidth; x++)
                temp.SetPixel(x, y, 255);

        masterImage = temp;

        masterImage.Lock();
        masterImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, masterImage.PixelWidth, masterImage.PixelHeight));
        masterImage.Unlock();

        if (OnMasterFrameCaptured != null)
            OnMasterFrameCaptured(this, new CameraFrameCapturedArgs(CameraType.Master, masterImage));
    }
```

Comment: Please include also the temp variable declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181132/edit-raw-pixel-data-of-writeablebitmap) post. I now can edit raw pixel data of any WriteableBitmap image before sending it to image control in WPF. Below is what I exactly used but here I just convert every frame to some transparency under a condition:

```
        public void ConvertImage(ref WriteableBitmap Wbmp)
    {
        int width = Wbmp.PixelWidth;
        int height = Wbmp.PixelHeight;
        int stride = Wbmp.BackBufferStride;
        int bytesPerPixel = (Wbmp.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* pImgData = (byte*)Wbmp.BackBuffer;

            // set alpha to transparent for any pixel with red < 0x88 and invert others
            int cRowStart = 0;
            int cColStart = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
            {
                cColStart = cRowStart;
                for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
                {
                    byte* bPixel = pImgData + cColStart;
                    UInt32* iPixel = (UInt32*)bPixel;

                    if (bPixel[2 /* bgRa */] < 0x44)
                    {
                        // set to 50% transparent
                        bPixel[3 /* bgrA */] = 0x7f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // invert but maintain alpha
                        *iPixel = *iPixel ^ 0x00ffffff;
                    }

                    cColStart += bytesPerPixel;
                }
                cRowStart += stride;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the routine of using it is like this:

```
        masterImage.Lock();
        ConvertImage(ref masterImage);
        masterImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, masterImage.PixelWidth, masterImage.PixelHeight));
        masterImage.Unlock();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have swapped X and Y, i represents height, j represents width, then you shouldcall SetPixel like:

```
temp.SetPixel(j, i, 255);
```

On cases like this is better to use meaningful names for variables, like X and Y.

Comment: You are right, I just saw the function prototype too. I swapped them but however, I am still getting the same error, AcessViolationException

Comment: SetPixel is not part of WriteableBitmap, so you have an extension or component, post the function's code.

Comment: But we both just used it. How come it's not part of WritableBitmap?

Comment: I have an extension like that, and WriteableBitmapEx also implemented it. Look at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I see. Thanks. I just added the whole thing, maybe you can help?

Comment: Still missing where SetPixel comes from... and the problem should be there.

Comment: It comes from the System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmapExtensions, and basically I just saw it in intellisense suggestions when typing '.' after the WritableBitMap instance.. couldn't  find its body though

Comment: Maybe you added the WriteableBitmapEx component? I think it comes from there, then, if that's the case I would ask on the component support forum/contact form on your case.

Comment: well I am working on someone else's code and yeah I just noticed. Thanks I will do that